# Read multiple values from 1 input line in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, io

I want the user to enter two numbers with a space between them, then take the two numbers and place them in a 2-element array. For example it would look like:

```
Please enter two values:
  >> 1 6
```

Where `array[0] = 1` and `array[1] = 6`

How would I do this in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably using `scanf()`:

```
if (scanf("%d %d\n", &i1, &i2) != 2)
    ...oops...
```

Comment: In `"%d %d\n"` the `\n` is no different from the space. It'd be better to do `"%d %d%c"` and check that the last character is `'\n'`.

Comment: You really don't want spaces or newlines in scanf formats in most cases. `"%d%d"` is much better.

Comment: In retrospect (2+ years later), I'd rewrite this answer. The trailing space (newline) in a format string is a disaster if the code will be driven by a human because the input won't stop scanning until EOF or until it gets something that is not a white space.  It is generally better to handle such cases with `fgets()` to get the whole line and use `sscanf()` to handle the parsing. There are ways to determine whether the whole of the input was used (just two number and white space). The white space in the middle of the format is less of a problem - indeed, a non-problem in the current scenario.